# cannot access asset folder inside document root on centOS

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, digital-ocean

I was able to finally get my site up and running on DigitalOcean and after getting some help on ServerFault the certificates are all in order.

However, I cannot seem to get access to my asset folders once I access the site

The site URL is: https://www.zandu.biz or https://zandu.biz

this link should work
https://zandu.biz/icons/menu/menusection_humanresources.jpg

but it doesn't

Any advice on what i missed here?

the /var/www/html/zeintek/merlin/front_end/dist/ folder is the document root and where index is located.

[image]

here is my apache conf file:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80
Listen 8029

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerName localhost
ServerAdmin nicolas.zein@zeintek.com

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel info

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
IncludeOptional conf/v-hosts/*.conf
```

here is my vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerAdmin nicolas.zein@zeintek.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/zeintek/merlin/front_end/dist/"
  ServerName zandu.biz
  ServerAlias www.zandu.biz

  <Directory "/var/www/html/zeintek/merlin/front_end/dist/">

    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py 
    Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    Options +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All 
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From All

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

   </Directory>

  ErrorLog "logs/webservicesliveroot1.zeintek.com-error.log"
  CustomLog "logs/webservicesliveroot1.zeintek.com-access.log" common

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8029>

  ServerAdmin nicolas.zein@zeintek.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/zeintek/merlin/back_end/public/"
    ServerName zandu.biz
  ServerAlias www.zandu.biz

  <Directory "/var/www/html/zeintek/merlin/back_end/public/">

    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py 
    Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All 
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From All

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

   </Directory>

  ErrorLog "logs/webservicesliveroot2.zeintek.com-error.log"
  CustomLog "logs/webservicesliveroot2.zeintek.com-access.log" common

</VirtualHost>
```

here is my ssl vhost file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

  LogLevel warn
  SSLEngine On
  #we need to prevent the POODLE attach to v3 of SSL is disable. Also we need to enable forward secrecy so disable v2
  # SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
  #for forward secrecy
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
  #for forward secrecy
  #SSLCipherSuite EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS
  SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zandu.biz-0002/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zandu.biz-0002/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zandu.biz-0002/chain.pem

  #unused for now
  #SSLCACertificateFile NOTUSEDFORNOW  #If using a self-signed certificate or a root certificate provided by ca-certificates, omit this line

  ServerAdmin nicolas.zein@zeintek.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/zeintek/merlin/front_end/dist/"
  ServerName zandu.biz
  ServerAlias www.zandu.biz

  <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Files>

  <Directory "/var/www/html/zeintek/merlin/front_end/dist/">

    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py 
    Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All 
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From All

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

  </Directory>

  TransferLog "logs/webservicesliveroot3.zeintek.com-transfer.log"
  ErrorLog "logs/webservicesliveroot3.zeintek.com-error.log"
  CustomLog "logs/webservicesliveroot3.zeintek.com-access.log" common
  BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  #CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
  #  "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8039>

  LogLevel warn
  SSLEngine On
  #we need to prevent the POODLE attach to v3 of SSL is disable. Also we need to enable forward secrecy so disable v2
  # SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
  #for forward secrecy
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
  #for forward secrecy
  SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zandu.biz-0002/cert.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zandu.biz-0002/privkey.pem
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/zandu.biz-0002/chain.pem

  #unused for now
  #SSLCACertificateFile NOTUSEDFORNOW  #If using a self-signed certificate or a root certificate provided by ca-certificates, omit this line

  ServerAdmin nicolas.zein@zeintek.com
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/zeintek/merlin/back_end/public/"
  ServerName zandu.biz
  ServerAlias www.zandu.biz

  <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </Files>

  <Directory "/var/www/html/zeintek/merlin/back_end/public/">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py 
    Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All 
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow From All

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
  </Directory>

  TransferLog "logs/webservicesliveroot4.zeintek.com-transfer.log"
  ErrorLog "logs/webservicesliveroot4.zeintek.com-error.log"
  CustomLog "logs/webservicesliveroot4.zeintek.com-access.log" common
  BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
  #CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
  #  "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What changes did you make to the Apache configuration?

Comment: Quite a few, i can paste it here, is it safe for me to do so?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Hello Michael, i updated my question with all the info. Thank you very much for your help on this issue.

Comment: Hmm. Well the first obvious problem is that your DNS records do not resolve to your server's address. They seem to be resolving to some GoDaddy URL shortening service.

Comment: where do you see this @MichaelHampton?

Comment: I clicked on one of your URLs. Actually I clicked on all of them and they all exhibit the same problem.

Comment: that's cause i made a rookie mistake. It's zandu.biz i'll edit my question right now, the third link is correct not working for the reason i posted this thread. My apologies. Anything you find odd in my config files?

Comment: OK, now I can see your web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Apache configuration shipped with CentOS includes an `Alias` which causes URL paths beginning with `/icons/` to be loaded from another directory.

In `/etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.conf` you will find:

```
Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/httpd/icons/"
```

Because your icon isn't in that directory, you get an Apache 404 error.

You should comment out or remove that line from the file.

Comment: will try that immediately, will revert back shortly. Thanks. Try jedi.luke@star-wars.com / secret to login and see the urls now loading in the ERP. It's not just icon though but let me start with your advice and see.

Comment: You are an absolut genius @MichaelHampton!!! I wish i could give you a million stars. Thanks!!!!